# How to initialize list with parent child relation

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, datareader

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
public class Parent
{
   public string name;
   IList<Child> children;
}

public class Child
{
  public string parentName;
  public int age;
}
```

As it is understandable, each parent can have multiple children, and we can have multiple parents. What is the best way to initialize these classes? Is it better to get all of the parents, and all of the children from database then use LINQ?

```
IList<Parent> parents = GetParents() //assume this gets parents from db
IList<Child> children = GetChildren() //assume this gets children from db
foreach(Parent parent in parents)
{
   parent.children = children.Where(x=>x.parentName == parent.name).ToList();
}
```

or get all of the parents and iterate through each parent to query database by parentName to get children information? Due to requirement that I have, I cannot use datatable or dataset; I can only use datareader.

```
IList<Parent> parents = GetParents()//assume this gets parents from db
foreach(Parent parent in parents)
{
  parent.children = GetChildrenByParentName();//assume this gets parents from db by parentName
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the "Children" db table have a link to "Parents" table, have "parentId" column for example? If so, then if You use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework to access the db they will handle the relationship for You.

Comment: Due to requirement, I cannot use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework, I can get data through datareader only. "Children" db table only has parent name, no other related information. Parent name is the only link between these two.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to leverage LinqToSql, Entity Framework or some other custom querying method and you must load all the parents and their children in the database per the manor you suggest then your first option is most likely superior. Assuming you'll query all the rows of both tables, the first option will result in only two database queries. In the second option you'll have as many queries as there are children plus the query for the parents.

**EDIT**

Additionally, especially if the data sets are large you can achieve further performance by using [Enumerable.ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx). This essentially creates a sorted dictionary for you which makes searching for the appropriate children much more efficient as the framework can make use of a binary search. You could use it as follows:

```
var children = GetChildren().ToLookup(p => p.parentName);
```

... and then in your loop ...

```
parent.children = children[parent.name].ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if parents and children have the basic fields, you should have one Table for them in database, and have an additional property `Parent`, which references to the same table - row , (so it points to its parent in database) you can determine, if the row is child or parent, if it has `Parent` not null, then it should be the child element of row with `Parent`